# How do you manipulate $4\cos(2\theta)\sin(2\theta)-\pi$; to get; $2\sin(4\theta) - \pi$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you manipulate $4\cos(2\theta) \sin(2\theta)-\pi \,$ to get $\, 2\sin(4\theta) - \pi$?

I'm trying to improve my algebra. I found those two answers from differentiating $\sin^2(2\theta) - \pi\theta$ but I don't understand how to get from $1$ to the other.

Thanks.

Comment: Double angle formula: $\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$

Comment: Notice that $\sin(4\theta)=2\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)$ then $2\sin(4\theta)=2\times 2\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)=4\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta).$

Comment: You might as well start by adding $\pi$ to both sides of the question; then your left with just the use of the [double-angle identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) for $\sin$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the double angle formula $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ thus when you put into that form you get $2\cdot \sin(4x)-\pi$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**$$\sin(A+ B) \equiv \sin A \cos B + \sin B \cos A$$